# How to compare two Pandas DataFrames based on specific columns in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Pandas DataFrames:

```
a =
     ID  Index     Value
1   275      0  00000005
2  1024     27        01
3  1024     23        01

b = 
     ID  Index Value_x Value_y
1  1024     27      01      02
2  1024     23      01      02
```

I want to get only the different values based on the *first three columns*, but only preserving the columns of `a` - thereby resulting in this:

```
     ID  Index     Value
1   275      0  00000005
```

I've tried dropping columns first, and doing a diff that way, but that ends up creating unnecessary copies of the DataFrames (real world arrays are 100k+ rows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `merge` with `indicator=True` and slice on "left_only":

```
cols = ['ID', 'Index']
c = (a.merge(b[cols], on=cols, how='outer', indicator=True)
      .loc[lambda x: x.pop('_merge').eq('left_only')])
```

output:

```
    ID  Index  Value
0  275      0      5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can play with a `MultiIndex` to perform this without needing to create temporary `DataFrame` or unnecessarily copying data:

```py
# 1
idx_a = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(a.iloc[:, :3])
idx_b = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(b.iloc[:, :3])

# 2
idx_diff = idx_a.difference(idx_b)

# 3
result = a.set_index(idx_a).reindex(idx_diff).reset_index(drop=True)

print(result)
    ID  Index     Value
0  275      0  00000005
```

1. Create `MultiIndex` objects from the first 3 columns of each `DataFrame`
2. Get the index values that appear in `idx_a` but not in `idx_b`
3. Use this difference index to subset our original `DataFrame` (`a`)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible way. You can join both dataframes to form one dataframe and then drop the duplicate values.

```py
import pandas as pd

a = [
    [275, 0, '00000005'],
    [283, 0, '00F0'],
    [1024, 27, '01']
]

b = [
    [283, 0, '00F0', '00E1'],
    [1024, 27, '01', '02']
]

# create dataframe for a and b
df_a = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['ID', 'Index', 'Value'])
df_b = pd.DataFrame(b, columns=['ID', 'Index', 'Value_x', 'Value_y'])

# get difference of df_a and df_b based on ID and Index
df_diff = pd.concat([df_a[['ID', 'Index']], df_b[['ID', 'Index']]]).drop_duplicates(
    subset=['ID', 'Index'], keep=False)

print(df_diff)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `anti_join`:

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, anti_join, tribble
>>> a = tribble(
...     f.ID,  f.Index,  f.Value,
...     275,   0,        "00000005",
...     1024,  27,       "01",
...     1024,  23,       "01",
... )
>>> b = tribble(
...     f.ID,  f.Index,  f.Value_x, f.Value_y,
...     1024,  23,       "01",      "02",
...     1024,  27,       "01",      "02",
... )
>>>
>>> a >> anti_join(b, by={"ID": "ID", "Index": "Index", "Value": "Value_x"})
       ID   Index     Value
  <int64> <int64>  <object>
0     275       0  00000005
```

I am the author of [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) package, which is backed by pandas. Let me know if you have any questions or issues.